# Operator == not compatible with types contract IERC20 and address

Tags: solidity

My goal is to compare my `IERC20` contract with my `address repaymentCurrency` in a require statement:

`require(currency == listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency, "Error");`

However, I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: Operator == not compatible with types contract IERC20 and address`

Any ideas about what's going on?

Here are my structs:

```
struct Listing {
      Loan loanDetails;
      address lenderAddress;
    }

    
    struct Loan {
      address[] erc20acceptedAddresses; // @dev Borrowers can include a list fo ERC20 tokens they'll accept from the lender
      uint256[] erc20repaymentAmounts; // @dev Front-end calculates how much of ERC20 tokens shoould be paid back
      address repaymentCurrency;
    }
```

Here is my currency interface:

```
IERC20 currency = IERC20(listing.loanDetails.erc20acceptedAddresses[_erc20repaymentIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicitly convert the imported IERC20 address to an address. if you declared currency as an IERC20,it comes as an interface. Hence, cannot be compared with a normal address. try this:

```
require(address(currency) == listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency, "Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitely convert your IERC20 instance to an address. `require(address(currency) == listing.loanDetails.repaymentCurrency, "Error");` will work